# Check for errors doing string to float conversion, when 0.00 is an accepted value

Tags: php, string, null, double

I am currently looking for the most elegant way, to do error-checking on a string to float conversion, when 0.00 shall be an accepted value, but non-numeric characters shall lead to a bailout.
Currently I am thinking of testing the string for any other chars than ","/"." or "[0-9]". I`d just like to know, if there is a more elegant/shorter way.
Thanks in advance, Oliver !

Comment: rtm, is_numeric(), also is_float()

Comment: *Currently I am thinking of testing the string for any other chars than **","/"."** or "[0-9]* - which tends to imply that the thousands separator or non-en formatted numbers should be accepted? In which case `is_float()` (or indeed `is_numeric()`) will actually fail on things like `100,000.27` or `100.000,27` - if that's the case you might want to check the `NumberFormatter` class http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a built in function for this.

`is_float()`

Examples:

`is_float(27.25); // This would be true`

`is_float('abc'); // This would be false`

Comment: 3 isn't a float, and that function will FAIL. use is_numeric()

Comment: His question asked to check whether something is float, *not* whether something is numeric. In this case, using `is_numeric()` would actually be incorrect, as it would accept numbers that are not floats. Obviously, if he wants to accept non-floating point numbers too then it would be correct, but this is not what he asked for.

Comment: Yes, but first things first. He is doing a string to float conversion. First thing you need to do is validate that the string is numeric. Again, is_float() on its own will fail.

Comment: That would be a waste. `is_float()` does check that the string is numeric, but with a decimal point. Using `is_numeric` before that would be pointless.

Comment: $string ='45'; echo is_float($string) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // output: no https://3v4l.org/anWH2

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for `is_numeric()`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

```
$x = 5.345;
$y = '0.00';
$z = 'abc123';

echo is_numeric($x)."1\n";
echo is_numeric($y)."2\n";
echo is_numeric($z)."3\n";
```

See it working here https://3v4l.org/sEvqC